# Converting from .las to .ply and vice versa in Python?

Tags: python, lidar, las, point-cloud, ply

I am trying to convert a .las/.laz file into .ply file, read the .ply file, do some processing on it and then convert it back to .las/.laz file.

Is there any Python implementation for this?

For reading a .las file, I use the below code:

```
inFile = laspy.file.File(folder + '.las', mode='r')
```

I have tried searching for next steps and found [this](https://github.com/daavoo/pyntcloud) but unable to use it as I want.